# Single field instead of several fields

Tags: database-design, performance

There is a relational database with the following Users table

```
User
Id
Name
Age
Parents
Friends
Colleagues
...
```

And there are tables Parents, Friends, Colleauges, etc. Due to specifics of database this part of User info is actually a single document that is always used as whole piece

```
Parents
Friends
Colleagues
...
```

Are there any advantages to remove all this tables and use the following Users table instead

```
User
Id
Name
Age
People
```

Where people are document with a special structure, for example, JSON or XML? This database is not truely relational. Will it be faster, easier to develop and maintain, etc.?

Comment: I don't understand your current structure.  Do you have a single field that lists all the parents/friends/colleagues?

Comment: Currenty I have traditional relational design where several tables (Parents, Friends, Colleagues, ...) link to another table (Users) through foreign key. I am going to keep only one table (Users) which has single field (People - in TEXT format) that holds all the data of removed tables for specific user in JSON format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "Are there any advantages to remove all this tables and use the
>   following Users table instead"

It depends.  Are you talking about a lot of rows?  Or just a few?  How about the number of different data fields in a "People" document?  Parsing something like that (for a lot of fields) is not going to be easy or performance-friendly.  Especially if the fields are not consistent across the documents.

> "Where people are document with a special structure, for 
>   example, JSON or XML?  This database is not truely relational"

Given these statements (and others) it almost sounds to me like this particular instance would be better served with a (NoSQL) MongoDB solution.  Essentially, you could have a "People" database and save collections of "Parents", "Friends" and "Colleagues."  MongoDB stores documents in collections as BSON, or a binary-encoded serialization of JSON.

Here's a link to the MongoDB site which explains a little about [BSON and MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/BSON).  Hope this helps.